# Ajax return data without an } ending

Tags: php, ajax

I have a stange issue when using ajax. My success data is truncated.

There my ajax function :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url, //url to connexion function
    data: {form: $('#jforms_users_connexion').serializeArray()},
    success: function(data)
    { 
      alert("enter success");
    }});
```

There is my php function

```
function connexion()
{ 
  $rep = $this->getResponse('json'); //my php will return an json array
  $rep->data = array("data" => "toto");
  jLog::dump($rep);
  return $rep;
}
```

The dump give this

```
default jResponseJson::__set_state(array(


'data' => 
  array (
    'data' => 'toto',
  ),
   '_type' => NULL,
   '_httpHeaders' => 
  array (
  ),
   '_httpHeadersSent' => false,
   '_httpStatusCode' => '200',
   '_httpStatusMsg' => 'OK',
   '_outputOnlyHeaders' => false,
   'httpVersion' => '1.1',
   'forcedHttpVersion' => false,
))
```

But on firebug, the response is {"data":"tt"

There no '}', also the alert doesn't work

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure your AJAX call isn't missing a `});`?

Comment: use fiddler to see what exact data your server is returning, or just run the URL in browser and see if return data has } or not, I am sure your PHP code is not returning the required }

Comment: You ajax function is complete? Theres no the `});` closing the function.

Comment: My bad, i miswrite. There actually the '});' at the end.

@SumitGupta, yes, the function return {"data":"tt" but why ? I dont see anything wrong :/

Comment: well you are using custom code, so cannot tell much, but just echo closing tag, or what I use is, I create Array of my data and just use json_encode function from PHP, why use external library when PHP has such cool function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little syntex error with your ajax code-

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url, //url to connexion function
   data: {form: $('#jforms_users_connexion').serializeArray()},
   success: function(data)
   { 
    alert("enter success");
   }
 });
```

You were missing closing tags '});'.

Comment: My bad, i miswrite. There actually the '});' at the end. I wrote a bit too fast my question :D